# Issues with code telling me if user is entering letter/number or neither

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with the following bit of code I have. I'm new to JavaScript so please if giving me a solution can you explain it to me thanks. The more I learn the better :).

This is the code I currently have.

```
let upperLower = prompt("please enter either a uppercase letter, lowercase letter or a number");
if( (upperLower.toUpperCase() == upperLower.toLowerCase() ||   isNaN(parseInt(upperLower)))) {
    console.log(upperLower + " is not a letter or number");
}
else if (!isNaN(parseInt(upperLower))){
    console.log(upperLower + " is a number");
}
else if (upperLower == upperLower.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log(upperLower + " character is lowercase");
}
else if (upperLower == upperLower.toUpperCase()) {
    console.log(upperLower + " character is uppercase");
}
```

My problem is that no matter what I enter it says it is not a letter or number.

what should be happening is if the user enters a letter for example like "L" it should the user that the letter is lower case or if they enter a number like "1" it should tell them "1 is a number" and if they enter something like "?"it should say "? is neither a letter or a number.

Comment: Just for what it's worth on your just-deleted question about a water calculator, you said *"I need to do this using else if statements"* I'm guessing this is an assignment of some kind, but just so you know, what you've described isn't a good fit for `if`/`else if`/`else`. There's an argument for using `if` in the solution, but not `else if` or `else`. Still, if they're requiring that you use it, you'll have to do that, just be aware that they're pushing you the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really a problem with javascript, but actually logic. On the first condition you check if it isn't a letter, so it will result `true` if it's a symbol or number. On the second condition you check if it isn't a number, so a letter or symbol will result `true`.

Now the problem is that you're checking if the first OR the second condition is true. So if it's a number, it will be true on the first condition and enter the if, if it's a letter or a symbol it will be true on the second condition and enter.

To correct this you need to use `&&` instead of `||`, so only when the two conditions satisfy it will enter the if.

```
if( (upperLower.toUpperCase() == upperLower.toLowerCase() && isNaN(parseInt(upperLower)))) {
    console.log(upperLower + " is not a letter or number");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it now works and thank you for also taking the time to explain it to me, Greatly appreciated